# Is there an alternative for Autorun.inf for Windows 7 / 8 / 8.1 / 10?

Tags: windows, autorun

For a customer we created a software which will be installed at about 350 USB sticks. Now we want that this .exe is automatically executed when the stick is plugged into the PC.

A few years ago we used the simple `autorun.inf` method.

But for Windows 7 and later Windows versions this function is not longer working as I've seen. That makes me a little bit wondering because in my system control I can select how the drive will be opened. At "software and games" I selected "always ask", then I put this `Autorun.inf` on the stick:

```
[autorun]
open=Demo1.exe
```

But it's not working. The only thing that Windows makes when I plug the stick into, it asks whether I want to open the drive folder.

What I have to do that the software starts automatically OR a window opens in which the user can decide to run the executable or don't do that?

Comment: http://thenextweb.com/insider/2011/06/28/us-govt-plant-usb-sticks-in-security-study-60-of-subjects-take-the-bait/#!r1pYl

Answer (score 3):

For Windows 7 and later only optical drives can specify auto run tasks. Indeed earlier versions of Windows can be patched to behave the same way. This change was made in response to the Conficker worm.

So your goal simply cannot be achieved. You will need to instruct users to explore the memory stick and run a specific program manually.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot specify autorun.inf tasks for USB drives. Read here for futher Information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2009/04/27/improvements-to-autoplay.aspx

Answer (score 1):

And Microsoft released for Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows Server 2003 and Windows Server 2008 the security hotfix **KB967940** explained on page [Microsoft Security Advisory (967940)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/SecurityAdvisories/2009/967940) which disables the autorun feature for all drives except CD and DVD drives.

See also:

- MSRC blog post [Deeper insight into the Security Advisory 967940 update](https://msrc.microsoft.com/blog/2011/02/deeper-insight-into-the-security-advisory-967940-update/) written by Adam Shostack
- ZDNet article [Microsoft disables AutoRun on Windows XP/Vista to prevent malware infections](https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-disables-autorun-on-windows-xpvista-to-prevent-malware-infections/) written by Dancho Danchev

It is not possible anymore that something is automatically started when a writable USB flash memory device is plugged in to prevent malware to run automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers from *David Heffernan* and *Mofi* are right. Only CD/DVD/Optical drives are allowed to specify auto run tasks.

BUT, if you identify the manufacturer of the USB chip and get the firmware management tool for this chip, you can reconfigure it and get the USB to appear as a CD drive to the OS.

If this seems an overhelming task, you can get your USB created by some companies dedicated to the distribution of multimedia content.

Comment: @user3187598: Sometime ago i had to deal with the inverse process, removing the cd partition from usb memories. Any manufacturer is viable. The problem is getting the firmware tool for the specific chip. Almost all can be found digging in internet. For the opossite process (your case) and your volume of units, some advertising company like [this](http://www.usbpromos.com/data-preloading-custom-usb-promos-usb-drives/) (the first i found with google, just included as example), will cost you less than the time i had to invert to get everything working.

Comment: @user3187598: anyway, [chipgenius](http://agnipulse.com/2010/03/chipgenius-and-usbdeview-usb-information-tools/) will be your best start. Alcortools (google it) will be probably your next reference. And always try things on a clean machine. And once finished a reinstall will probably be necessary. Once one start to install specific manufacturer drivers to low level USB management, the rest of USB drives behaves strangely (sometimes).