# Filepath by hostname, date and time

Tags: date, batch-file, time, hostname, xcopy

Hi I am brand new to batch file coding.  I've been teaching myself Excel VBA for the past few months and StackOverflow was a very helpful site for me.  Here is what I am trying to accomplish.

My company works a lot with IP video surveillance servers.  Before we work on servers we like to take a snapshot of the log and configuration files for the various programs we use in case something goes wrong.  I would like to get this down to a BAT file that resides on the technician's USB stick with an autorun file that will execute the BAT file when the USB is plugged into the machine.  The program would go out to the various files and copy them to the file path: \hostname\date\time\originalfoldername\thisfile.xml   I have been pulling code from various sites and here's what I've come up with so far to get me to the filepath: \date\time\originalfoldername\thisfile.xml

```
@echo off 
rem COPYIT.BAT transfers all files in all subdirectories of
rem the source drive or directory (%1) to the destination rem drive or directory (%2) 


for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims==" %%i in (`wmic os get LocalDateTime /VALUE 2^>NUL`) do if '.%%i.'=='.LocalDateTime.' set ldt=%%j
set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2%\%ldt:~8,2%%ldt:~10,2%

echo %ldt%



xcopy "C:\ProgramData\Milestone\XProtect Recording Server"          "\"%ldt%"\XProtect Recording Server\" /s /e
xcopy "C:\ProgramData\Milestone\XProtect Management Server"         "\"%ldt%"\XProtect Management Server\" /s /e
xcopy "C:\ProgramData\Milestone\XProtect Management Client"         "\"%ldt%"\XProtect Management Client\" /s /e
xcopy "C:\ProgramData\Milestone\XProtect Event Server"              "\"%ldt%"\XProtect Event Server\" /s /e
xcopy "C:\ProgramData\Milestone\XProtect Log Server"                "\"%ldt%"\XProtect Log Server\" /s /e
xcopy "C:\ProgramData\Milestone\XProtect Data Collector Server"     "\"%ldt%"\XProtect Data Collector Server\" /s /e
xcopy "C:\ProgramData\Milestone\XProtect Report Web Server"         "\"%ldt%"\XProtect Report Web Server\" /s /e
xcopy "C:\ProgramData\Milestone\XProtect Service Channel Server"    "\"%ldt%"\XProtect Service Channel Server\" /s /e
xcopy "C:\ProgramData\Milestone\XProtect Smart Client"              "\"%ldt%"\XProtect Smart Client\" /s /e


if errorlevel 4 goto lowmemory 
if errorlevel 2 goto abort 
if errorlevel 0 goto exit 

:lowmemory 
echo Insufficient memory to copy files or 
echo invalid drive or command-line syntax. 
goto exit 

:abort 
echo You pressed CTRL+C to end the copy operation. 
goto exit 

:exit
```

I have also found the code for the hostname but I can't figure out how to put them together.  Here is that code:

```
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET MYVAR=%%i
ECHO %MYVAR%
```

Can someone help?  Thanks.

Comment: First, forget the idea about automatically executed batch file after plugin USB device. For the reason see [Autorun.inf alternative at Windows 7/8](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21076969/3074564).

Comment: Second, open a command prompt window and executed `help set` or `set /?` and look on last help page displayed. You will read about **%CD%**, **%DATE%** and **%TIME%** and the methods available for modifying the values of environment variables as `set ldt=%ldt:~0,4%-%ldt:~4,2%-%ldt:~6,2%\%ldt:~8,2%%ldt:~10,2%` in posted code does. This line also shows how to concatenate the strings of several environment variables to a new string, for example to build the string for the target directory path.