# How to silently copy files from computer using an usb stick?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, usb, autorun

I tried using batch files and autorun.inf, but it does not worked on win 7/8 pc, anyone plz help me? any software?

Comment: You mean you want to just plug in the stick and then automatically run some program that copies files, without notifying the user? I certainly hope that that's not possible, for security reasons.

Comment: sounds like you're making a virus.

Comment: Flagged, off-topic for Stack OverFlow as this question is clearly a security violation.

Comment: any softwares for that?

Comment: See [Autorun.inf alternative at Windows 7/8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076969/). BTW: I have configured my Windows XP and Windows 7 computers to never run something automatically on any drive including CD/DVD-ROMs. Many companies do that also for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 does not allow the use of autorun.inf files. It can cause virus files on a flash drive to automatically run and possibly sabotage the computer. Also, it doesn't seem like a good idea to create this type of file anyway. If incorrectly used it could steal important information from the user. So, it won't work on Windows 7 and is a bad idea for other systems.