# Unable to run a bat with autorun.inf from USB

Tags: windows, batch-file, usb, autorun, inf

I have a autorun.inf file in my pendrive to to run a bat file automatically whenever i plug my Pen drive in my system. The autorun.inf code is as below

```
[autorun]
Icon=bat.ico
Label=Murali Manohar
Open=check.bat
ShellExecute=check.bat
UseAutoPlay=1
```

The rest of that are working fine. I can see my icon got changed and the name of my pen drive too changed. But the bat file seems to be not running

the below is what i have in my bat file

```
mkdir Murali
```

But i don't find anything due to this bat file.

Note:

**1) I tried to plug the pendrive in Windows 8 Operating system.

2) auto-run turned on in Windows**

Comment: This functionality was removed several years ago for security reasons

Comment: Thank you for your answer alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autorun.inf alternative at Windows 7/8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076969/autorun-inf-alternative-at-windows-7-8)