# How to run a program automatically from an USB drive when USB drive is plugged-in?

Tags: batch-file, usb-drive, autorun

I've been trying to create an automatically started application on an USB drive that executes a batch file. I have tried a lot of codes for the `autorun.inf` for example:

```
[autorun]
open=PStart.exe
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off
echo Test
pause > nul
```

But when I plug-in the USB drive nothing happens.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Autorun has been disabled for quite some time now. Unless you're using something older than windows 7, this is impossible.

Comment: If I'm using windows 7 is it possible?

Comment: No, only older versions

Comment: @DennisvanGils It certainly is possible for Windows 7. [su] has the answer of course :)

Comment: See [WIndows 7 Autoplay completely disabled - how to re-enable?](https://superuser.com/q/223840)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autorun.inf alternative at Windows 7/8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076969/autorun-inf-alternative-at-windows-7-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I solve this problem?

> If I'm using windows 7 is it possible?

On Windows 7 it is possible.

> Control Panel -> Programs -> Default Programs -> Change AutoPlay
>   settings,
>
> Adjust as required.

Source [Windows 7 Autoplay completely disabled - how to re-enable?](https://superuser.com/a/223911/337631) answer by [Ankur Dholakiya](https://superuser.com/users/58493/ankur-dholakiya)